# how to chain 2 different event handlers between factory functions?

Tags: javascript, events, import, event-handling, factory-pattern

I have 2 buttons, called `ButtonA` and `ButtonB`. Each buttons have their own event handlers and also being scoped by each different function factories.

And I want to chain these 2 buttons to set an argument as a global variable in one of factories called `Worker`, but somewhat reason `Worker` cannot register the argument.

This is the result when I clicked `buttonA` 1 time then `ButtonB` 3 times in order to.

```
> Order receives from Manager manager.js:9  
> Responses in Worker worker.js:9
> Meal worker.js:11
> Responses in Worker worker.js:9
> undefined worker.js:11 // It should return Meal 
> Responses in Worker worker.js:9
> undefined worker.js:11
> Responses in Worker worker.js:9
> undefined worker.js:11
```

Here's the code:

```
// manager.js
import Worker from "./worker.js";
const Manager = (() => {
   var upperChain = (elem) => {
       elem.addEventListener("click", Interface.sendOrderToWorker);
   };
   const Interface = {
       sendOrderToWorker: async (event) => {
           // do something..
           console.log("Order receives from Manager");
           Worker.getReceipt("Meal"); // Send data from here
       }
   };
   return {
       upperChain: (elem) => upperChain(elem)
   };
})();
export default Manager;

// worker.js
const Worker = (() => {
    // this.string;
    let food;
    var lowerChain = (elem) => {
      elem.addEventListener("click", (event) => Interface.getReceipt());
    }
    const Interface = {
        getReceipt: async (string) => {
            console.log("Responses in Worker");
            food = string;
            console.log(food); // Receives data from here.
        }
    }
    return {
        lowerChain: (elem) => lowerChain(elem),
        getReceipt: (param) => Interface.getReceipt(param)
    }
})();
export default Worker;

// index.js
import Manager from "./manager.js";
import Worker from "./worker.js";

let buttonA = document.getElementById("buttonA");
let buttonB = document.getElementById("buttonB");

Manager.upperChain(buttonA);
Worker.lowerChain(buttonB);
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I read this correctly, but when you call `getReceipt()` in the `Worker.lowerChain` you don't pass a string argument. But in the `getReceipt()` you set the food to some string. => when you click the button the food value becomes `undefined`;

EDIT for clarification:

```
import Worker from "./worker.js";
const Manager = (() => {
   var upperChain = (elem) => {
       elem.addEventListener("click", Interface.sendOrderToWorker);
   };
   const Interface = {
       sendOrderToWorker: async (event) => {
           console.log("Order receives from Manager");
           Worker.getReceipt("Meal"); // Will set food to "Meal" in Worker
       }
   };
   return {
       upperChain: (elem) => upperChain(elem)
   };
})();
export default Manager;

// worker.js
const Worker = (() => {
    let food;
    var lowerChain = (elem) => {
      elem.addEventListener("click", (event) => Interface.getReceipt()); // Since calling getReceipt without arguments will leave 'food' as is because argument 'string' is undefined
    }
    const Interface = {
        getReceipt: async (string) => {
            console.log("Responses in Worker");
            food = string || food; // Here food was ALWAYS set to string..but string wasn't always set
            console.log(food);
        }
    }
    return {
        lowerChain: (elem) => lowerChain(elem),
        getReceipt: (param) => Interface.getReceipt(param)
    }
})();
export default Worker;

// index.js
import Manager from "./manager.js";
import Worker from "./worker.js";

let buttonA = document.getElementById("buttonA");
let buttonB = document.getElementById("buttonB");

Manager.upperChain(buttonA);
Worker.lowerChain(buttonB);
```

Comment: Once I clicked `ButtonA` the argument should be set as a global in `Factory` module because I set `food = string`. Then I want to return the value `food` by clicking `ButtonB`.

Comment: I know but if string isn't set when calling the function you set food to undefined.

Comment: Look at the edit. I would recommend you add another function so that you have one to set `food` and one to get `food`.

Comment: I've just solved it. I got a hint from your word `... you set food to undefined`, so I added logical operator `||` then it works. `food = string || food;`. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you edit your code.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant.... but I would still recommend using seperate functions because getReceipt doesn't really sound like it should change any values.

Comment: Ok. Changed it know.